# Scroll to position using Skrollr on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax, skrollr

Is there a way to scroll to a position on a page on mobile using javascript? I'm currently using the skrollr library, and while great on desktop, I can't seem to get any scroll methods to work to take a user to a specific position on the page onclick.I've tried libraries like scrollTo and jquery to try and work, but it seems as if skrollr has problems with these methods.

I have the following function:

```
function scrollAbout() {
                document.getElementById("nav").style.height = "0%";
                window.scroll({
                    top: 2180, 
                    behavior: 'smooth' 
                });
            }
```

And here's the DOM element with the function applied:

```
<li onclick="scrollAbout();"><a class="menuitem" style="text-align:center;" id="tour">ABOUT</a></li>
```

On a side note,

I keep getting the following error which is probably why I can't get the click to work.

```
skrollr.min.js:2 Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080(anonymous function)
```

Can anybody see how I might achieve click to scroll position despite skrollr?